# DrawableBottom Error in Android Sdk 17

Tags: android

I have a **Button** in my activity's layout like this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_before"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_navigate_before"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_2" />
```

It is ok when I run my app to a device with Android SDK >19 but when I run my app to a device with Android SDK <19 like 17, my activity unfortunately stopped and this error occurs:

```
11-16 08:57:41.042 3549-3549/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.SearchActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class Button
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class Button
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                 at com.myapp.app.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:90)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_navigate_before.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02007d
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1958)
                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                                                 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:769)
                                                 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                 at com.myapp.app.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:90) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                              Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1955)
                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 
                                                 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:769) 
                                                 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087) 
                                                 at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                 at com.myapp.app.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:90) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I remove this line from my layout XML activity runs ok in every device:

> android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_navigate_before"

And **ic_navigate_before** is an XML file:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/gray_2"
    android:pathData="M15.41,7.41L14,6l-6,6 6,6 1.41,-1.41L10.83,12z"/>
</vector>
```

Also, my app min SDK is 16.
What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 23.3.0 version vector drawables can only be loaded via app:srcCompat or setImageResource(). [see here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html).

you can get VectorDrawable to work as drawableLeft (etc.) but it depends on the Support Library version and it comes with a price.the best way to take this issue i found is, remove drawable bottom from xml and add drawable bottom programmatically.

```
navigateBefore.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0, 0, 0, R.drawable. ic_navigate_before);
```

Comment: How can I verify my drawables resolution?

Comment: @behrooz.fard is ic_navigate_before drawable defined by a XML file as state drawable, shape drawable or png, jpg?

Comment: It is an XML file. I put it to my question now.

Comment: It is in question.

Comment: ```android:fillColor="@color/gray_2"``` change to android:fillColor="#929292". change to hexcode color. and let me know its working

Comment: if its not working.remove drawable bottom from xml and add drawable bottom programmatically 

```navigateBefore.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0, 0, 0, R.drawable. ic_navigate_before);```

Comment: Your first answer is not worked, but when I add drawable programmatically it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Hi refer this document for why the crash was occuring.

[As it stated that 'You’ll find directly referencing vector drawables outside of app:srcCompat will fail prior to Lollipop.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)'

As I Know,
We cant directly set vector drawable.
**From 23.3.0 version vector drawables can only be loaded via app:srcCompat or setImageResource()**

Try below solution,
create new file drawable_navigate_before.xml file write down below code.

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_navigate_before"/>
 </layer-list>
```

and now set this file as drawable in you layout file.

```
     android:drawableBottom="@drawable/drawable_navigate_before"
```

Comment: What is your answer exactly do?

Comment: this will fix your crash

Comment: It solved my problem, but I want to know why this crash occurred?

Comment: wait i am updating my answer with reason.